# Firefox preference to set default permission for handling various protocols (e.g. "tel:" links)?

Tags: firefox, permissions, default-settings, about-config, protocol-handler

I have the tel: protocol's default handler set to Microsoft Your Phone, so I can place calls and send SMS from my computer. When I click a tel hyperlink in Firefox (e.g. `tel:(555)555-5555`), I get a FF prompt asking to Allow or Deny the website's ability to open this type of link, with an optional checkbox to remember this preference.

I would like to set a global default preference to *always allow* tel link handling by any website. However, I can't find any option in Settings (about:preferences) or about:config to make this happen.

In about:config, the preference `permissions.default.camera` controls the default behavior for webpage access to the camera, for example. A value of `0` is "Always Ask," and I think a value of `2` is "Always Deny," so I presume a value of `1` would be "Always Allow." I have tried creating new preferences named `permissions.default.tel`, `permissions.default.telephone`, and `permissions.default.phone`, but none of them have had any effect.

In fact, I can't even find a preference that stores the information about which sites I've granted permanent tel access to by using the "remember this decision" checkbox. Firefox has to store this data *somewhere*, so if I can even find that, maybe I can add "https://*.*" to the list.

So, how do I set the default preference to always allow handling of a specific protocol?

Answer (score 1):

In order to automatically open a protocol like tel: with the default assigned handler application, without being asked for site-by-site permission, navigate to about:config and create a new boolean preference `network.protocol-handler.external.tel`. Set it to `True`. (To globally deny permission to a protocol instead, you would set it to `False`.)